# Can jenkins expire multibranch jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

If a branch is deleted or the jenkinsfile is removed jenkins will remove the job.

Is there a feature to expire and black list old multibranch jobs? So I could expire multibranch jobs that havent run in a month and jenkins would delete those jobs and ignore those branches (even if a jenkinsfile was in them).

It would of course need to keep a list of expired branches somewhere and have a way to un-expire them. Is there a plugin for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Aged References SCM filter plugin is available for GitHub and other SCM: e.g. https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-scm-filter-aged-refs for GitHub

It might work for you: it adds a branch detection criteria that exclude branches that haven't had updates over an arbitrary period of time.
Your question suggests you're looking at jobs/branches that "haven't run" in a while, which would be the case if they haven't seen commits. But this plugin sort of ignores jobs that were triggered manually, I think.

With this plugin, you 'un-expire' a branch job by adding a new commit to it, essentially.

Comment: Can the bitbucket plugin do this kind of thing?

Comment: that will work for me. But it looks like these age filter plugins are for github and bitbucket only, not generic git repos.

Comment: hmm the plugin seems to be broken and hasn't seem commits in 8 months. I opened an issue

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer even though it's a partial and imperfect solution to your problem, much appreciated.

Comment: This plugin must have been fixed because it works now FYI